# Merge x11grab with v4l2 into single output file

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, recording, v4l2

I'm trying to record a video using `ffmpeg` from two inputs: webcam (`v4l2`) and desktop (`x11grab`). I checked that both inputs are working fine:

```bsh
ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -i :0.0 \
    -vcodec libx264 x11.mkv
ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 -s 960x540 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 \
    -vcodec libx264 v4l.mkv
```

but when I try to use both, only `x11grab` goes to output:

```bsh
ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -i :0.0 \
    -f v4l2 -s 960x540 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 \
    -vcodec libx264 test.mkv
```

Is it possible to merge these inputs into single output file and specify the position for video from webcam (move it to right bottom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the overlay filter within a filtergraph.

```
ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -i :0.0 \
    -f v4l2 -video_size 960x540 -framerate 25 -i /dev/video0 \
    -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h" \
    -vcodec libx264 test.mkv
```